# Make Div tag like body tag

Tags: html, css

I want to add background to div. If content height will be small, background will be cutted. If I add min-height, when window height is small, there are apeears scrollbar.. Help please)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window OR http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/hr8sL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jacob is all right, just add a width property also,

```
div {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#f00;
    color:#fff;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question but try this:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#f00;
    color:#fff;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you should use some javascript.

```
function wh()
{
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

document.getElementById('--your div ID--').style.height = height;
document.getElementById('--your div ID--').style.width = width;
}
```

Now call that function wh() on body load. i.e.,

```
<body onload="wh()"></body>
```